# Voting System in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a code that generates a voting system and your site. His appearance is as shown below:

[image: exemple]

I made the following code JavaScipt:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("a#up").click(function() {
    jQuery('.rating').html('');
    jQuery('#loading').show();

    post_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: ajax_var.url,
        data: "action=post_id&nonce=" + ajax_var.nonce + "&post_rating=up&post_id=" + post_id,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#loading').hide();

            jQuery('.rating').html(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});

jQuery("a#down").click(function() {

    post_id = jQuery(this).data("post_id");

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: ajax_var.url,
        data: "action=post_id&nonce=" + ajax_var.nonce + "&post_rating=down&post_id=" + post_id,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('.rating').html(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});

});
```

And the following PHP code is in my functions.php

```
    <?php

function add_rating_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('rating', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/rating.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_localize_script('rating', 'ajax_var', array('url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')));
}

function update_rating() {

    // Check for nonce security
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'ajax-nonce'))
        die('Busted!');

    if (isset($_POST['post_rating'])) {
        // Retrieve user IP address
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

        // Get voters'IPs for the current post
        $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");
        $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];

        if (!is_array($voted_IP))
            $voted_IP = array();

        // Get votes count for the current post
        $meta_count_up = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_up", true);
        $meta_count_down = get_post_meta($post_id, "votes_down", true);

        // Use has already voted ?
        if (!hasAlreadyVoted($post_id)) {
            $voted_IP[$ip] = time();
            if ($_POST['post_rating']  == 'up') {

                // Save IP and increase votes count
                update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
                update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_up", ++$meta_count_up);

                echo '<p class=\'message\'>Esse artigo já ajudou <span class=\'count\'>' . $meta_count_up . '</span> pessoas </p>';
            }elseif($_POST['post_rating'] == 'down'){
                update_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP", $voted_IP);
                update_post_meta($post_id, "votes_down", ++$meta_count_down);

                echo '<p class=\'message\'>Obrigado pelo seu voto.</p>';
            }

        }
        else
              echo '<p class=\'message\'>Você já enviou o seu voto.</p>';
    }
    exit;
    }

    function hasAlreadyVoted($post_id) {
    $timebeforerevote = 120;

    $meta_IP = get_post_meta($post_id, "voted_IP");
    $voted_IP = $meta_IP[0];
    if (!is_array($voted_IP))
        $voted_IP = array();
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (in_array($ip, array_keys($voted_IP))) {
        $time = $voted_IP[$ip];
        $now = time();

        if (round(($now - $time) / 60) > $timebeforerevote)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

wp_localize_script('rating', 'ajax_var', array(
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-nonce')
));

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_rating_script');
add_action('wp_ajax_post_id', 'update_rating');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_id', 'update_rating');
```

The problem is to prevent the user from voting multiple times in the same article I saved it the IP and do a comparison, but I believe that over time will leave the table WordPress charged and super slow. Does anyone know about something that I optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

One trick for optimization might be to set a cookie after they vote and look for that as a first line of defense.  This would stop quite a few calls back to the database in a large number of use cases.  If a cookie isn't set, only then check your table for an IP address to determine if they have already voted.

A cookie-only approach obviously wouldn't work since a user could switch browsers, clear cookies, etc - and for those users you'll look up their IP just as you are currently (although there could still be ways of circumventing this, and you may be preventing legitmate users from voting if they are sharing an internet connection/IP address - i.e. voting from the same Starbucks Wifi connection).

At least by checking for a cookie first you can proactively prevent a large number of potentially unnecessary database transactions.

Comment: Yes indeed it is a good idea!

I do not want something with a lot of security, just want to prevent a person click the button repeatedly.

If I stop it until it clear the cache, andis enough already.